# Prevent browser moving element when children are focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing a simple map. The map consists of a viewport, and the map image itself, which is actually a div with a background image.
The viewport is relatively positioned and it's overflow is hidden, and the map image is absolutely positioned within the viewport.
The map can be moved with the mouse within the viewport and the map can also be zoomed (just increasing the size of the image as the image is a .svg)

The map has points on it which the user can hover over to get a description in a tooltip of the point. The points can also be focused by tabbing to them.
Points are children of the map image div and are absolutely positioned by percentage (to retain the correct position when the map is zoomed)

When a point is focused, I want to move the map so that the point is in the middle of the viewport. I have written the code for this and it works fine. However, if a point is outside of the viewport (not visible) then the browser automatically tries to move the map so the point is visible. I don't want it to do this, as it is interfering with the code I have written to animate the map move. This is nothing to do with scrolling.

I am using jQuery and have tried e.preventDefault() and return false; in the focus handler for the map points but neither work.
Is preventing this behaviour even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code that use are currently using, and consider creating a dumbed-down JSFiddle for people to edit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the scroll value of the map viewport was being set by the browser in order to bring the map point into view. As I am moving the map by setting it's top and left positions, this is what was causing the issue.

The solution was to add the .scroll() event listener to the viewport and just set the scrollTop and scrollLeft values to 0 when the event is triggered